# How to tie a row in a particular model to a field in another in django

Tags: python, django, database-design, many-to-many, foreign-key-relationship

I have a problem with the following (simplified version) models:

```
Sponsor(models.Model):
     sponsor_name = models.CharField()

Concerts(models.Model):
     artist_name = models.CharField()
     sponsor = models.ManyToMany(Sponsor)
```

I go to the admin interface and add a new Sponsor, it automatically shows on any concert, all Sponsors show on all Concerts. That is not what I want, I want SOME sponsors to be on SOME concerts.

I realize this is a relationships problem.
I have tried:

```
Sponsor(models.Model):
     belongs_to = models.ForeignKey(Concerts)
     sponsor_name = models.CharField()

Concerts(models.Model):
     artist_name = models.CharField()
```

But now I can't reuse sponsors, I have to add a new one for each Concert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're mistaking possible values with actually chosen `Sponsor` in `Concert` model in django-admin interface.

Try this `python manage.py shell` and then `from yourapp.yourmodel import Concerts; Concerts.objects.sponsor_set.all()`. 
Result should contain only selected `Sponsors` for that model (I bet you'll see empty list).

Comment: ohh, Yup, i saw all values and i have to highlight the ones i want and then save, silly me. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want each concert to have multiple `Sponsor`s, and each `Sponsor` to be able to be associated with multiple `Concert`s, then you will want to use a `ManyToManyField` rather than a `ForeignKey`.

See the docs for that at https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#manytomanyfield

The problem is probably in how you are displaying your Sponsors--please be sure that when you're printing the concert out in your template, you're not selecting all Sponsors, but instead iterating over `concert_instance.sponsor.all()` queryset.